# What is this furry white stuff and little white bugs?

Tags: insects

The fluffy stuff was all around the branches and leaves near the middle and base of the bush. The little critters were on the underside of leaves. I also included a picture of the flower in case someone needs to identify the plant in order to answer this question.

[image: white silk]
[image: white bugs under side of leaf]
[image: flower of bush]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like White flies.  Nasty little critters.  When my heirloom iris got an infestation, I carefully removed the most infested leaves and put them in an enclosed bag and into the trash.  Then I blasted the leaves with my garden hose to scatter them.  I removed any thing else I found by hand and haven't had a problem since.  I read on the Old Farmer's Almanac to use an insecticidal soap like Safer Soap is a good idea too.  I just prefer using as little on my plants as I can.